# Initialise third party library using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to initialise a [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) instance when a certain component mounts using React hooks. On resize I want to destroy or update the Swiper instance depending on the viewport width.

I'm initialising the plugin with the `useEffect` hook where I'm calling a function stored as a `const`.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [swiper, setSwiper] = useSate(null);
  const element = useRef(null);

  const initSwiper = useCallback(() => {
    // swiper is always null here so I can't destroy the instance
    if (MediaQuery.is('large up') && swiper !== null) {
      return setSwiper(swiper.destroy());
    }

    if (MediaQuery.is('small up')) {
      const currentSwiper = new Swiper(element.current, swiperSettings);
      currentSwiper.init();

      return setSwiper(currentSwiper);
    }
  }, [swiper, swiperSettings]);

  useEffect(() => {
    initSwiper();
    window.addEventListener('resize', initSwiper);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', initSwiper);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={element}>...</div>
}
```

I would like to know how I can access the Swiper instance after initialisation. Should I use a `ref`? I'm not really sure what the best way is to handle this.

Comment: You should probably use a package that lets you use Swiper as a React component (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-id-swiper).

Comment: Not really an answer to your original question. But `initSwiper` is a dependency and should be included to your `useEffect`s dependency array. This is an interesting article: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: dont add unnecessary packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need state here. Since the `useEffect()` callback is a closure, and you don't use `swiper` outside of the closure, create a variable (`let swiper`), and assign the current instance of `Swiper` to the variable. You should also declare `initSwiper` inside the closure, and you don't need (and actually can't) to wrap it with `useEffect()` since the `useEffect()` block only runs on init.

**Note**: `swiperSettings` are not coming from the props or state, so the `useEffect()` block is not dependant on them. If you need to change it via `props`, pass them via a ref.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const element = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let swiper = null;

    const initSwiper = () => {
      if (MediaQuery.is('large up') && swiper !== null) {
        swiper = swiper.destroy();
      } else if (MediaQuery.is('small up')) {
        // swiper.destroy(); // should probably start by destroying the old swiper
        swiper = new Swiper(element.current, swiperSettings);
        swiper.init();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', initSwiper);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', initSwiper);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={element}>...</div>
  );
};
```

And used as a custom hook (as [suggest by @PatrickRoberts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61066754/initialise-third-party-library-using-react-hooks/61067597?noredirect=1#comment108037242_61067597)):

```
const useSwiper = () => {
  const element = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let swiper = null;

    const initSwiper = () => {
      if (MediaQuery.is('large up') && swiper !== null) {
        swiper = swiper.destroy();
      } else if (MediaQuery.is('small up')) {
        // swiper.destroy(); // should probably start by destroying the old swiper
        swiper = new Swiper(element.current, swiperSettings);
        swiper.init();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', initSwiper);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', initSwiper);
    }
  }, []);

  return element;
};

const MyComponent = () => (
  <div ref={useSwiper()} />
);
```

Comment: Would also work nicely as a custom hook if you rename `MyComponent` to `useSwiper` and `return element;`. Then in `MyComponent` you could just do `return ( <div ref={useSwiper()}>...</div> );`

Comment: Thanks Ori Drori! Is it best practice to name the components using camelcase?

Comment: Actually components' names should start with an uppercase (Pascal Case). I've updated the answer accordingly.